# UI-grid Swapping data on same grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have maintained One grid , and for each data from the back end replaced in the same grid . The grid works fine for the first time whichever data it is , but for the second time there is some problem with the css or the template . Here is the link for the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YUxYL7DXi2MX6B8UsEfO?p=preview)

Given below is the handler for each of the data that is loaded from the back end

```
    $scope.$on('dataLoaded', function (event, gridData, path, ext) {


  $activityIndicator.stopAnimating(300);
  // Setting up the path and extension for use in the service
  $scope.path = path;
  $scope.extension = ext;
  // There is a change in column for every different data set , so building the headers with the data
  var def = new Array();
  angular.forEach(Object.keys(gridData[0]), function (key) {
    def.push(
      {
        field: key, displayName: key
        //headerCellTemplate:'views/header-template.html'
      });
  });
  //Specify the columnDef: Each different data is supposed to have different columnDefs
  $scope.gridData = gridData;

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = def;
});
```

Comment: What changes in your column definitions between data query calls?  Do you really need to change the definitions?  Do you have a sample of alternate data returned?  Just FYI: I was able so solve similar issue with custom headers with ng-if statements, but I would need to see what really changes.

Comment: @Roman : Yes , I need to change the definitions , Or else , the second time data loads , only the data with same column names will be viewed in the grid . Suppose I have columns [Name , age , place ] the first time data is loaded , And for second set of data , I have [Emp_name ,age , region ] ,I will have only 'age' in the grid when the new data is loaded .

Comment: Instead of specifying {field:'field-name'} , I specified {'name':'field-name '} and it was working fine . I am not sure  , what can possibly be the reason , Thank You anyways.